# Java DecimalFormat Swedish Locale "se_SV" negativ number formating

Tags: java

So I'm sitting with some old code (java SE) that I've set up to java 1.8_181, somewhere along the way the java.text.DecimalFormat stop working with negative numbers. My example code below shows the issue:

```
    DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = new DecimalFormatSymbols(new Locale("sv", "SV"));
    DecimalFormat tmp = new DecimalFormat("#,##0", dfs);
    String test = "-150";
    Number num = null;
    try {
        num = tmp.parse(test);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        System.out.println("Number comma is: "+num);
    }
```

Which give me the following Exception:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable number: "-150"
    Number comma is: null
at java.base/java.text.NumberFormat.parse(NumberFormat.java:431)
at Main.Main.main(Main.java:90)
```

Acording to git the project file says on master it was java 1.8 (32 bit), i do not know which java 1.8 build but I'm currently using java 1.8_181 (64 bit).

However in the old .jar file this example did not throw a ParseException, appeared when I started to work with the code.

Does anyone know way it would stop being able to parase "-" in the string?

Comment: That code runs fine for me

Comment: Your locale should be `new Locale("sv", "SE")` btw

Comment: Yea, you'r right. But unfortunately that was not the source of my problem.

Comment: How ever for some reason when I restarted the computer due to an update this started to work. Might windows lock something?